# Bitcoin Core Wallet - Invalid Transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, wallet

A few months ago I tried to transfer my bitcoin but the transaction fee was too low which resulted in an Invalid Transaction. After eading about similar problems in this forum it is clear to me that the bitcoins are not lost but I need to convince my wallet to "ignore" the transaction. How can I do it with Bitcoin Core Wallet?
Thanks for a hint! Jozef

Comment: What was the fee rate used for this transaction?

Comment: Fee 0.00000190 BTC Here is the transaction: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/26c4e3f0e83d3e758093448ae0ef0226483de098892a4f26593b8cebda1a0ead

Comment: Is this your address `3P6WzoX1ZS1XiqJ7r5mcaL3q1qS1EYWWUa` ? Do you own the private key for this address?

Comment: 3P is my wallet on coibase.com. 1G is is wallet on my computer(Bitcoin Core).

Comment: Prayank, what could I do then?

Comment: Unfortunately can't do anything. Will have to wait for it to get confirmed or use https://viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator and make sure you enable RBF for all transactions in future.

Comment: Thanks, for txaccelerator this transaction does not exist ...

Comment: Prayak, how much time can it take? It happened 6 months ago. Or can bitcoin be just lost/forgotten?

Comment: That transaction has 4771 confirmations: https://blockstream.info/tx/26c4e3f0e83d3e758093448ae0ef0226483de098892a4f26593b8cebda1a0ead You should contact Coinbase support if its not credited in your account as you informed output (3P6WzoX1ZS1XiqJ7r5mcaL3q1qS1EYWWUa) for this tx is your Coinbase deposit address

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's there. So all is needed is just patience. A lot of patience ;)